# Set Case Comment to Public/IsPublished when certain criteria are met

Tags: unit-test, soap-api, case

## Goal

I am trying to check when Case Comments are created from a specific user, and their type is XXX then the case comments that are auto generated should be marked as Public or Visible in Self Service Portal.

## Problem

Problem is that when I try to set the caseComment.IsPublished = true, I get an error back stating that it is read only. "caused by: System.FinalException: Record is read-only". I also get this error message from my logs "11:00:59:985 FATAL_ERROR System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, afterInsertCaseComment: execution of AfterInsert"

## CLASS

```
public static void handleCaseComment(CaseComment caseComment)
    {
        System.debug('CaseComment ID:' + caseComment.Id);
        String CreatorId = [SELECT CreatedById FROM CaseComment WHERE Id = :caseComment.Id LIMIT 1].CreatedById;
        System.debug('CreatorID: ' + CreatorId);
        String CreatorName = [SELECT Name FROM user WHERE Id = :CreatorId LIMIT 1].Name;
        System.debug('CreatorName: ' + CreatorName);
                
        Case parentCaseType = getParentCaseType(caseComment);
        Case parentCaseSubType = getParentCaseSubType(caseComment);
        
        if(parentCaseType.Type == 'Type1' && CreatorName == 'CreatorXXX' && (parentCaseSubType.Subtype__c == 'Logs' || parentCaseSubType.Subtype__c == 'Validation'))
        {   
            caseComment.IsPublished = true;
        }
    }
```

## TEST CASE

```
private static User populateUsersDatabase()
    {
        sObject[] users = new sObject[]{};
        
        Profile profile = [SELECT id FROM Profile WHERE name='System Administrator'];
        User user = new User(LastName = 'AutomaticUser',
                            Username = 'fake@xxx.com',
                            Email = 'fake@xxx.com',
                            Alias = 'alias',
                            CommunityNickname = 'communitynickname',
                            TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Denver',
                            LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
                            EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
                            ProfileId = profile.Id,
                            LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US');
        users.add(user);
        
        Database.insert(users);
        
        return user;
    }

@isTest static void testPublishedComment()
    {      
        Case theCase = new Case();
        User user = populateUsersDatabase();
        CaseComment caseComment;
        System.runAs(user)
        {
            theCase.Type = 'Type1';
            theCase.IsVisibleInSelfService = true;
            insert theCase;
            
            theCase.Requester_Name__c = 'Processing';
            theCase.Subtype__c = 'Logs';
            update theCase;
            
            caseComment = new CaseComment(ParentId = theCase.Id,
                                          IsPublished = false);
            insert caseComment;
        }
        
        System.assertEquals(true, caseComment.isPublished);
    }
```

## Trigger

```
trigger afterInsertCaseComment on CaseComment (after insert) {
    for(CaseComment comment : trigger.new)
    {
        CaseCommentHandler.handleCaseComment(comment);
    }
}
```

Comment: welcome to stackexchange !

Comment: In the API, CaseComment records can't be modified after insertion unless the user has the “Modify All” object-level permission for Cases or the “Modify All Data” permission. If not, users can only update the IsPublished field, and can't delete CaseComment.

Comment: All I want to do is change the IsPublished field, so why does the Modify All permission matter in this case?

Comment: I'd like to see more of your code, honestly. I suspect that the error you are receiving is because you are trying to call DML on Trigger.new in the After context, which is not allowed. How are you obtaining the handle to CaseComment?

Comment: I'm also worried anytime I see a service method that passes a single sObject instance in Apex due to the constraints of DML and SOQL execution limits. If you call the handleCaseComment() method inside of a loop, you are setting yourself up for a governor limit exception some day. Your test should also test many records, again to ensure you are not going to exceed governor limits. Andy Fawcett just wrote a great series of articles on Apex Enterprise design patterns here: http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Apex_Enterprise_Patterns_-_Service_Layer

Comment: aplogies for overlooking this !@koerbcm can you post the trigger code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was able to reproduce the error and the error is in trigger only.

[image]

Your trigger is after insert it has to be before insert event .

```
trigger afterInsertCaseComment on CaseComment (before insert) {
for(CaseComment comment : trigger.new) {
    CaseCommentHandler.handleCaseComment(comment);
  }
}
```

And also there will be change in class as well

```
public static void handleCaseComment(CaseComment caseComment)
{
    System.debug('CaseComment ID:' + caseComment.Id);
    String CreatorId =userinfo.getuserID();//Note the changes
    System.debug('CreatorID: ' + CreatorId);
    String CreatorName =userinfo.getUserName();Note the changes 

    Case parentCaseType = getParentCaseType(caseComment);
    Case parentCaseSubType = getParentCaseSubType(caseComment);

    if(parentCaseType.Type == 'Type1' && CreatorName == 'CreatorXXX' && (parentCaseSubType.Subtype__c == 'Logs' || parentCaseSubType.Subtype__c == 'Validation'))
    {   
        caseComment.IsPublished = true;
    }
}
```

This code should work .

I think developer of this code had after event since he will be able to get createdbyId .I have workaround with userinfo class .

Comment: All I am trying to do is update the case comment with IsPublished = true. Would this still be the case then?

Comment: in test class you have inserted a casecomment with ispublished

Comment: Does modifyall need to be set in the test case when creating the user, or in the actual salesforce user profile?

Comment: Defaulting the IsPublished to false. I need the code to change it to true when needed.

Comment: modify all in case for the profile.

Comment: why dont you try with admin profile and that has modify all for sure

Comment: Do you know of any documentation about this subject, as this is the first time I have ever tried anything like this, and don't really know what I am doing?

Comment: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm.Use this and create a user of system admin profile .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10848/discussion-between-mohith-kumar-and-koerbcm)

Comment: Added the user to the admin group, but I am getting the same results. Moved to chat.

Comment: Why is this wrong?
`insert caseComment;//this is wrong .Need modifyall to set IsPublished`

Comment: Mohith, read your link again. The doc states the following: "CaseComment records can't be modified after insertion unless the user has the “Modify All” object-level permission for Cases or the “Modify All Data” permission. If not, users can only update the IsPublished field, and can't delete CaseComment." I think you've misread this. This appears to state that *any* user who has write permission on the record can modify IsPublished. Special permissions are only needed for other fields.

Comment: aplogies for overlooking this !@koerbcm can you post the trigger code

Comment: Posted Trigger code above.

Comment: updated the answer

Comment: getUserName gives me their UserName not Last name which is what I am using in this case, however,changing it to before solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: For getting last name there userinfo.getuserlastname() or some thing.Refer userinfo class